# how to add fields dynamically by clicking on multiple checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I want to add two fields dynamically by clicking on mutiple checkbox's checkbox.
first field is a label with choosen a value from multiple checkbox and another one is text box for the user to enter their value.

```js
 
 jQuery('#size').on('change', function() {
  
   
   
  
   
    var vauler=jQuery(this).val()
    
    jQuery('#mytable ').append("<tr><th id='this"+vauler+"' width='33%'> size-"+vauler+"</th>  <td><input type='text' name='sizeThis' value="+vauler+"></td> </tr>")
  
 });
```

```html
  
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-sm-4 control-label no-padding-right" for="form-field-1"> Sizes </label>
              <div class="col-sm-7">
                   <select id="size" class="multiselect" multiple="" name="preferred_manufacturer[]">
      <option value="1">one</option>
      <option value="2">two</option>
      <option value="3">three</option>
      <option value="4">four</option>
      <option value="5">five</option>
     </select>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="space-4"></div>
            
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-sm-4 control-label no-padding-right" for="form-field-1">Quantity </label>
              <div class="col-sm-7">
              
    <table class="table-hover table table-bordered table-striped" id="mytable">
      
                    <tr>
            <th width="33%">size-sizeSelectedFromMultiple</th>
       <td>
        <!--<a href="SubProduct.php" class="btn btn-block btn-sm">Click New Window</a>-->
        <div class="form-group">

        <div class="col-sm-7">
        <input type="text" id="form-field-1"  name="otmcolor"  placeholder="Quantity" class="col-sm-12" />
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="space-4"></div>

       </td>
         </tr>
                  </table>

     
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="space-4"></div>
```

Comment: Add fields to what? What must do after clicking on checkbox?

Comment: fields need to append in  a div

Comment: Like this?! https://jsfiddle.net/ep8ca6m8/
if you click on checkbox, checkbox number and Quantity value added to table as a row.

Comment: if it is just multiple select your answer is ok.i want it in multiple select checkbox.for multiple checkboxes,i am getting array values and that is appending in label and text box.i need it seperate values without commas in both label and text box as jsfiddle shows

Comment: Excuse me, but I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: am using drop down checkboxes for select element